# How do I search a XElement with an specific attribute value?

Tags: c#, xml, search, xelement

I need to search a child node by a value of one of its attribute, for example say that I have this XML

```
<Root>
    <Child Name="1" foo="a"/>
    <Child Name="2" foo="a"/>
    <Child Name="3" foo="b"/>
    <Child Name="4" foo="c"/>
    <OhterTag/>
</Root>
```

I want to extract the node Child with the attribute Name with value 2 . . .  I want the full node not just the tag of the node.

I have tried something like this

```
root.Elements("Attr").Where(child => child.Attribute("Name").Value == "2");
```

but I have not work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the element name, which is "Child" and it should work the way you have it... And since `.Where` in this case returns an `IEnumerable<XElement>`, to get just that Element, use `.First()` at the end.

```
root.Elements("Child")
    .Where(child => child.Attribute("Name").Value == "2")
    .First()
```

... or you can just use the predicate with `.First()`

```
root.Elements("Child")
    .First(child => child.Attribute("Name").Value == "2")
```

Finally you can use .FirstOrDefault() in case the node doesn't exist, to avoid null reference exceptions, as per discussion in below comments, suggested by @HamletHakobyan

```
root.Elements("Child")
    .FirstOrDefault(child => child.Attribute("Name").Value == "2")
```

Comment: Use `FirstOrDefault` to avoid exception.

Comment: All depends on the application design and the expected input, but yes that's an option as well.

Comment: If in question used term `search`, so it is applicable `not found` answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You can, *if you want to*, achieve the same using `XPath` -

```
using System.Xml.XPath;

// ...

XElement result = root.XPathSelectElement("//Child[@Name='2']");
```